# How to remove null values from each column in dataframe and append non-null column values in 1 row based on a key

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am validating the data b/w 2 different data sources by using pandas and pandasql . After the validation , i am storing the mismatches in new dataframe . The issue is , for a column key , in each row , i have mismatched column as not null values , while other columns being null .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWq52.png)
I tried using df.stack() but couldn't achieve much.

For a given key , i want all mismatched columns in 1 row , rather than , multiple rows containing mismatched columns in each row .

Actual dataframe representation is in image .
I provided a sample Below : (Bi,Bj) -> pairs of (expected , actual) column values .

```
 sample = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':[10,10,10] , 'B1':['CMBS-Cash','Nan','Nan'],'B2':['CMBS','Nan','Nan'] ,'B3':['Nan','CMBSCASH','Nan'],'B4':['Nan','Eternit','Nan'] ,
                         'B5':['Nan','Nan','CMBS'],'B6':['Nan','Nan','Cash']})

 final = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':[10] , 'B1':['CMBS-Cash'],'B2':['CMBS'] ,'B3':['CMBSCASH'],'B4':['Eternit'] ,'B5':['CMBS'],'B6':['Cash'] })
```

Comment: This would be clearer with some sample data and the code that you tried already

Comment: i have added the image of Dataframe , showing the problem statement.

Comment: An image is almost as useless. Give some data in a former that can be easily cut and pasted+ the result you expect from that minimal example.  Check the SO faq on how to post a good question

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]? Basically, create sample dataframe and add desired output.

Comment: current df structure -> ` sample = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':[10,10] , 'B1':['CMBS-Cash','Nan'],'B2':['CMBS','Nan'] ,'B3':['Nan','CMBSCASH'],'B4':['Nan','Eternit']})  `   and output i wanted ->  ' final = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':[10] , 'B1':['CMBS-Cash'],'B2':['CMBS'] ,'B3':['CMBSCASH'],'B4':['Eternit']}) `

Comment: So in dataframe `sample` you have no overlapping values? And the dataframe will only have 2 columns? (Please edit the question itself and add the example code there)

Comment: U r right , for 1 key  A = 10  , there will be no overlapping values . Dataframe will have many columns (see image attached ) , i just provided a sample .

Comment: Can Anybody look into this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iff you fill the "NaN" values with `""`, you can use `groupby` and `sum`

```
final = sample.fillna("").groupby("A").sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: fillna("") didn't worked out as "Nan" was populating as string . However , using above approach i was able to figure out . Thanks .


    `     for i in sample.columns.difference(['A']):
               sample[i] = sample[i].str.replace('Nan',repl=" ")
          sample.groupby("A").sum()   `